# Is it possible to NOT auto-open files on select in VisualStudio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

It's annoying me because I often just select files.

And I don't want to wait while parsers will do all their jobs and spam me with warnings...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go `Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows`:

[image]

and edit settings in "Preview Tab".

Comment: Yeah VS is a speed demon.

Comment: Ah MSFT, giving a new definition to "preview."